# what is {d '2013-12-01'} in teradata query

Tags: teradata

I am quite new to teradata. I came across a query where I see **{d '2013-12-01'}** expression . Can some one tell me what is all about?

```
SELECT
  CASES.CASE_ID, CASES.CREATION_TIMESTAMP, CASES.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CASES.AGENT_ID
FROM
  CASES
WHERE CREATION_DATE = {d '2013-12-01'} AND AGENT_ID IN ('aaaaa','bbbbb','ccccc') ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** based on a_horse_with_no_name's comment:

`{d '2013-12-01'}` is an ODBC/JDBC escape sequence for a DATE.

If you try to run this select using .NET/CLI it will fail. Better use `DATE '2013-12-01'` instead.

Comment: It will work in JDBC as well, because JDBC uses the same escape syntax. But I agree that using an ANSI date literal is a better choice.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for that hint, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot ! @dnoeth : Can you please share URL of reference documents details similar syntax.

Comment: @Sanjiv: You mean for the DATE syntax? It's in the TD manuals: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1143_112A/ch02.043.053.html

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth for the link . No what talking about syntax similar to {d '2013-12-01'}

Comment: @Sanjiv: Simply google for "odbc escape literal date", e.g. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234%28v=sql.90%29.aspx